# GnuWin grep End-of-Line Anchor

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, grep

I have GnuWin installed on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64 machine.  I am trying to use grep 2.5.3 to match lines containing the word "true".  The following is my working use-case:

```
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true'
```

The above matches both lines.  Now I want to exclude the second line using the end-of-line anchor `$` (dollar sign).  I have tried the following variants, none of which match either line:

```
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\\\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\\\\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^^^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^^^^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true$$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\^\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\\^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^^\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\^\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^\\$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true\^^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^\^^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^\^$'
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true^^^\$'
```

I also tried each of the above using double quotes instead of single quotes, which also didn't work.  Does anyone know how to anchor the regular expression to the end of the line, such that only the first line from my example ("true") matches?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a combination of problems.  `(echo true & echo true2)` (I edited that mistake out of my question since it wasn't relevant to what I really wanted to know) actually outputs the following on a Windows machine:

```
true \r\n
true2\r\n
```

So the first issue is that my echo commands included an extraneous space character.  The second issue is that `grep` treats `\n` as the end of the line, which is explained in an answer to [Why is the end-of-line $ anchor not working with the grep command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176505)  So the second problem is that I need to capture the `\r` character in my regular expression.  Therefore, the following is what it takes to get this working:

```
(echo true& echo true2) | grep 'true[[:space:]]*$'
```

Comment: Which version of grep are you using?  Mine reports 2.5.3.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting.  I just updated my Cygwin (to 2.9.0, which includes grep 3.0), and I'm still observing that $ only matches \n.  Were you running in a Cygwin command prompt, or the Windows command prompt?

Comment: Late Correction: `echo true|find "true"` matches, `(echo true)|find "true "` matches. Advice for fellow readers: Windows `cmd` is FUBAR.

Comment: Also I was wrong on `\r\n` matched by `$` as `grep` seems to remove all `\r` from input.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin: `(echo true; echo true2) | grep true$`

GnuWin:`(echo true & echo true2) | grep "true $"`

In cmd, `(echo true & echo true2)` actually gives `true \r\ntrue2\r\n`

Comment: Ah, nice catch with the whitespace issue.  However, your GnuWin approach is still not working for me.  Perhaps I missed something: `(echo true & echo true2) | grep "true $"` still doesn't match anything.

Comment: @Jeff: bummer... what about `| grep -P "true\s+"`?

Comment: Yep, that did it for me.  Is it that `grep` doesn't include `\r` in the `\s` character class, whereas Perl does?

Comment: It is unfortunate that `grep` doesn't support multiple patterns with the `-P` option.  In my case, I have to decide between merging all of my regular expressions into one really long one, or use the dirty `[[:cntrl:]]` hack that I found elsewhere.

Comment: @Jeff what do you mean by multiple patterns? care to give an example?

Comment: Late reply: Perl `\s` = `[\t\v\n\f\r ]` = grep `[[:space:]]`. AFAIK, backslash character class is not recognised by grep.

Comment: By multiple patterns, I mean I am calling it like `grep -e "Pattern1" -e "Pattern2" ... -e "PatternN"`, where my patterns are incredibly non-trivial (mostly due to the complexity of batch escape sequences).